# node.js npm oracledb install error

Tags: node.js, npm

**Why should not the installation?**

```
`
    gyp ERR! build error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
    gyp ERR! stack at F (/home/appm/node_js/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:78:19)
    gyp ERR! stack at E (/home/appm/node_js/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:82:29)
    gyp ERR! stack at /home/appm/node_js/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:93:16
    gyp ERR! stack at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
    gyp ERR! System Linux 3.7.10-1.1-desktop
    gyp ERR! command "/home/appm/node_js/bin/node" "/home/appm/node_js/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd /home/appm/node_js/lib/node_modules/oracledb
    gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.4
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
    gyp ERR! not ok 
    npm ERR! Linux 3.7.10-1.1-desktop
    npm ERR! argv "/home/appm/node_js/bin/node" "/home/appm/node_js/bin/npm" "install" "oracledb"
    npm ERR! node v4.2.4
    npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

    npm ERR! oracledb@1.5.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@1.5.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the oracledb package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
    npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracledb
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/appm/node_js/lib/npm-debug.log

    317 info install oracledb@1.5.0
    318 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    319 info oracledb@1.5.0 Failed to exec install script
    320 verbose unlock done using /home/appm/.npm/_locks/oracledb-3df4b11d85532d05.lock for /home/appm/node_js/lib/node_modules/oracledb
    321 verbose stack Error: oracledb@1.5.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    321 verbose stack Exit status 1
    321 verbose stack at EventEmitter. (/home/appm/node_js/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:214:16)
    321 verbose stack at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    321 verbose stack at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
    321 verbose stack at ChildProcess. (/home/appm/node_js/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
    321 verbose stack at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    321 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    321 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
    321 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit(internal/child_process.js:211:5)
    322 verbose pkgid oracledb@1.5.0
    323 verbose cwd /home/appm/node_js/lib
    324 error Linux 3.7.10-1.1-desktop
    325 error argv "/home/appm/node_js/bin/node" "/home/appm/node_js/bin/npm"    "install" "oracledb"
    326 error node v4.2.4
    327 error npm  v2.14.12
    328 error code ELIFECYCLE
    329 error oracledb@1.5.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    329 error Exit status 1
    330 error Failed at the oracledb@1.5.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
    330 error This is most likely a problem with the oracledb package,
    330 error not with npm itself.
    330 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    330 error     node-gyp rebuild
    330 error You can get their info via:
    330 error     npm owner ls oracledb
    330 error There is likely additional logging output above.
    331 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
    332 verbose unbuild node_modules/oracledb
    333 info preuninstall oracledb@1.5.0
    334 info uninstall oracledb@1.5.0
    335 verbose unbuild rmStuff oracledb@1.5.0 from /home/appm/node_js  /lib/node_modules
    336 info postuninstall oracledb@1.5.0
    337 silly gentlyRm /home/appm/node_js/lib/node_modules/oracledb is being purged from base /home/appm/node_js/lib
    338 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /home/appm/node_js/lib/node_modules/oracledb
    339 silly vacuum-fs purging /home/appm/node_js/lib/node_modules/oracledb
    340 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /home/appm/node_js  /lib/node_modules 
`
```

```
os : opensuse 12.3
db : oracle 11g express
instant client sdk : 11.2.0.4.0
node.js : v4.2.4
```

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: _"Error: not found: make"_. So you need to install `make`.

Comment: Thanks!! solved by installing the make.